# How can I use ANSI encoding characters in Command Prompt Windows7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, fonts

Way back in the DOS days, I could have a command line prompt that contained block characters, such as █ or ▀.

I am trying to create a prompt with colored block characters using AnsiCon on Windows 7.

I have the coloring sorted out, but when I use those characters with any of the fonts available under Properties in the command prompt window (Consolas, Lucida Console, and Raster Fonts), they appear as other special characters.

Is there a font that I can install that supports the block characters using ANSI encoding?

Comment: I’m not sure about your use of “ANSI encoding” in this question, it sounds more like you are asking about using ANSI escape sequences like `←[1;33;44m`. It would probably be better to use “Extended ASCII” instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here: [How to use non-English characters?](https://superuser.com/questions/625866/cmd-how-to-use-non-english-characters)
Summry: You have to change your Command Prompt page code, then you can use UTF-8 characters using "Lucida Console" font.